# Android:How to refer css file within html in following situation 

Tags: android, webview

hi
In my application i need to display a html page in webview and that html page should refer to sdcard location for .css file (Using link href="...." tag).
I placed 2 files (i.e) html and css ) in sdcard->mibook.
I tried by giving absolute path as `link href="/mnt/sdcard/mibook/0.css"` 
how can i specify path name android?

**Edited:**
**Above problem solved :** by using this- **link href="file:///sdcard/mibook/0.css"**
But i have following requirement,
i need to handle around 50+ html file every time ,

I placed all files as follows,
**mibook->book1->pg90.sqlite**
**mibook->book1->links->o.css and 1.css**
The sqlite file contains html pages. each html page has css reference as **link href="/links/0.css"**
These css file should be refer by html. how can i do this?

Comment: If both the files resides in same directory, why full path, just the filenames should work.

Comment: how are you loading the html file into the webview?

Comment: @Doon my idea is little strange. becoz my html file contained in a sqlite file.Each row represents a html page and i retrieving by accessing each row. do u want to see that code?

Comment: don't need to see that,  Does each row contain a link the html page? or the actually text of the page?  How are you loading it into the webview?  something like webview.loadUrl('file://sdcard/mibook/book1/chaptr1.html');  if you are doing it that way then relative links *should* work, but i've never tried.

Comment: @Doon no like this way: String webContent=null;
Cursor cur=mDB.query( "MI_PAGE",null,null, null, null, null, null, null);
              cur.moveToPosition(5);
              webContent= cur.getString(4);
cur.close();               mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("about:blank",new String(webContent), "text/html", "UTF-8","" );

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String) . perhaps try setting baseUrl to the file://sdcard/ location. that should let the relative links work.

Comment: @Doon i used base url exactly as "file://sdcard/mibook/book1/". But it is not working.. why? anything missing?

Comment: @Doon The sqlite file contains whole html page...

Comment: Hmm I not sure exactly why it doesn't work, my guess is a security thing, but you are saying mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///sdcard/mibook/book1",String(webContent),"text/html","UTF-8","");  Fails to grab the links?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

`link href="file:///sdcard/mibook/0.css"`

Assuming Android >= 2.1