# how to Load a css file for html page android web view

Tags: android, css, webview

How to link a particular css file to a html page every time.The css files stored in sdcard folder. and html page contains the relative path to the css file. i used loadwithbaseurl(), but it is not working...

Comment: For more detail see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192772/androidhow-to-refer-css-file-within-html-in-following-situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, it should be as simple (and standard) as using the `<link href` in the head of your HTML/template:

```
<link href="css/stylesheet.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Just adjust the target to where your CSS file is.

Is this what you were meaning?

Comment: my html page is not intended to edit. in html page there is a relative link as:link href="/links/0.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet". i hve 0.css file. where do need to place this?

Comment: for complete question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192772/androidhow-to-refer-css-file-within-html-in-following-situation